# Distcc blocks ip when using portage

Tags: networking, gentoo, distcc

```
distcc[20890] (dcc_get_hostlist) read hosts from environment
distcc[20890] (dcc_parse_hosts) found localhost token "localhost"
distcc[20890] (dcc_parse_hosts) found tcp token "192.168.0.26"
distcc[20890] (dcc_check_backoff) still in backoff period for 192.168.0.26
distcc[20890] (dcc_remove_disliked) remove 192.168.0.26 from list
```

When compiling regularly, it works with no issue but when I use portage it doesn't compile on the other pc as well as not showing progress in Distccmon's even as root not even showing localhost.

I already added the host PC on /etc/hosts /etc/distccd/hosts $HOME/.distcc/hosts (on both root and user)

Comment: How are you setting up `distcc`? Are you using `FEATURES="distcc"` [as documented here](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Distcc#With_Portage)?

Comment: If already set it up in my make.conf, portage wouldn't be causing these errors if I didnt